# Crossing out as many pairs in a not decreasing series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose you have a non decreasing series $a_1\le a_2\le a_3\ldots\le a_n$ 
We can modify our series by only one operation: you can cross out a pair if and only if $2a_i\le a_j$. How can we ensure to delete as many elements as possible?

Comment: A greedy algorithm should work. Delete the largest possible pair in each move, that is $\max_{j,i} \{2a_i \le a_j\}$.

Comment: But can you ensure it will the highest possible number of elements?

Comment: Intuitively, it should. Large numbers are "bad" for the choice of $i$ and good for the choice of $j$, so eliminate them first. Pick $i$ as large as possible so we don't lose any small numbers unnecessarily.